# How can I move the mouse pointer on Linux without actually moving the mouse?

Tags: linux, mouse, gui

How can I move the mouse pointer on Linux without actually moving the mouse?

Comment: Platform? Language? Anything that will put this question into context?

Comment: Which OS/language?

Comment: I'm not sure whether moving mouse pointer without mouse is a best practice :)

Comment: sounds like someone is trying to prevent themselves from going idle.

Comment: That's a very ambiguous question... what are you trying to achieve? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 8):

You can move mouse to a specific location like (200,200) using command 'xdotool mousemove 200 200'

Comment: Note: You have to install the `libxdo3` and `xdotool` packages first. For Debian-based systems: `sudo apt install xdotool`.

Comment: @Fanatique And if you have installed the `command-not-found` package you will automatically get hints about the command you need to run when attempting to use a command that you haven't installed.

Answer (score 2):

Press `right alt` key with `shift` key with `num lock` key.

Now if we press the numbers it will move the mouse pointer! 5 performs a left-click.

Comment: RAlt+Shift+NumLock doesn't work for me, what does work is `setxkbmap -option 'keypad:pointerkeys'`, then Shift+NumLock

Answer (score -1):

In windows, you can set this up in the `Control Panel`, under `Accessibility Options` in the `Mouse` tab. Checking the `UseMouseKeys` box allows you control the mouse with the keyboard.

Comment: sorry I am a linux user

Comment: The question is clearly about linux and windows here is totally irrelevant!